# Using htaccess to check file in another directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, file-exists

Ok, I am starting to wonder if this is even possible. I have been pouring over htaccess tutorials and examples and I just can't seem to get it working right.

I have a script that creates dynamic images running in a directory on a friends website. I have access to / but the actual directory I am using is in /mydir/. In order to display the images they are output to png via PHP. I have the following *RewriteRule* setup to take the filename requested and run a PHP script. Each filename represents a separate file with a serialized object used in the display.php script

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.jpg$ display.php?file=$1
```

That part is working fine, however if someone requests a file that doesn't exist it just throws PHP errors because the script gets called but there is no object for it to use.

What I am trying to do now, and utterly failing at, is to have it check if the file exists in ./Cache/ directory then run the script as usual and if not then the server can just throw a standard 404.

I have tried things like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\.jpg$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT ROOT}/img/Cache/%1.jpg -f
```

and other combinations of REQUEST_URI, REQUEST_URL, SCRIPT_FILENAME, SCRIPT_NAME, etc. I can't seem to come up with the proper variable and regex expression to handle this so I am turning to you guys for help. The biggest problem is not knowing what is actually in each of those variables so I can see where I am going wrong. I would kill for some kind of var_dump(),

Comment: Please provide: 1) example URL with image you want to rewrite; 2) Where images are stored (relative to the website root); 3) As I understand `display.php` is located in website root? 4) Where .htaccess file is located where you have all these rules.

Comment: @LazyOne Sorry about that, thought I included that information. Guess I shouldn't make posts at 3AM. .htaccess and display.php are stored in www.website.net/mydir/img/ while the file I need to check is in www.website.net/mydir/img/Cache/.  An example URL to be checked and rewritten is www.website.net/mydir/img/66bb_1b5b6.jpg. I need to know if that file exists in the Cache folder, if so, rewrite as noted in OP, if not, then let the server throw a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/mydir/img/Cache/$1.jpg -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.jpg$ display.php?file=$1 [L]
```

1. This needs to be placed into .htaccess file in `/mydir/img` folder
2. If you move this folder somewhere else or rename parent folder, you will need update it as well in `RewriteCond` line.

---

If you wish you can try this approach, which is more flexible (no need to specify parent folder names) but I cannot guarantee that this will work on your setup (but it DOES work on my PC):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*)/([^/]+)\.jpg$
RewriteCond %1/Cache/%2.jpg -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.jpg display.php?file=$1 [L]
```

Here the current physical folder is determined automatically from requested URL. But if you have symbolic links or some other settings, it may produce incorrect results. Plus .. it has 1 more Condition .. which makes it a bit slower (1 extra regex to check).

Comment: That worked, thank you! So does the RewriteCond get the $1 variable from the RewriteRule? Doesn't the RewriteCond get processed first? Does this mean that I could keep the .jpg for the URL (needed to allow sites to process it as an image) but keep the actual cached file with a different extension? Would it work by just changing the extension on the RewriteCond?

Comment: @Sign No, RewriteRule need to match first part against URL first, if matched then it goes trough RewriteCond. If ALL matched, then rewrite occurs. Yes, you can keep cached files with different extension.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the PHP file to check it:

use `file_exists` in your PHP and if it does not exist, use `header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");` or `header('Location` to a 404 image

Comment: I considered doing that, but I was hoping to use .htaccess so that I could still use the server 404 page instead of having to develop my own or just having a blank screen.